# how to determine, by command line, whether my SATA sockets are connected or not to a device?

Tags: powershell, sata, wmic

I'm far from office and I would need to buy a SATA Hard Disk for a PC.

I can't ask anyone in office to open the case, then I thought to a command (wmic or powershel for example) to get if those SATA ports are connected to something (and, if possible, what device is connected).

I'm struggling googling this but can't find anything, do you think it's possible?

thanks!

Comment: I already read it but, at the end, I would not know how to match the numbers found, with the physical port

Comment: You can find port numbers in the motherboard manual.

Comment: then there is no other command I can use to directly find what I need?

Comment: Windows only knows port number, it cannot know the layout of the motherboard.

Comment: ok, right, can I ask you how to get the motherboard manual?

Comment: Get the manual from the website of the manufacturer.

Comment: apologies for the low level of my questions, but I don't know how to get any info of the motherboard, for example how to get the manufacturer?

Comment: Just google the model of the motherboard, find the website of the manufacturer, click on Support and then download the manual. This works for most motherboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question title asks for a command line method, here is the way to find which hard drive is connected to what motherboard port:

```
# query for wmi objects
$drivers = Get-CimInstance win32_pnpsignedDriver -filter 'DeviceName="Disk drive" OR DeviceName="CD-ROM Drive"'
$disks = Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPEntity | ? {$_.service -in 'disk','cdrom' -and $_.name -ne 'Xvd'}  # Xvd is an xbox/windows-store-related device

# Iterate through disks
$result = foreach ($disk in $disks) {
  # disk controllers are usually either IDE (IDE/SATA) or SCSI (NVME/M.2/virtual)
  $controller = Get-CimInstance -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'}" | 
    Where {$_.CreationClassName -in 'Win32_IDEController','Win32_SCSIController'}

  # the driver class lists drive location
  $driver = $drivers | where DeviceID -eq $disk.PNPDeviceID

  # combine data for result
  $disk | select Name,
    @{l='location';e={$driver.Location}},
    @{l='controllerName';e={$controller.Name}}
}
$result
```

and the output looks like:

```
Name                      location                         controllerName                                         
----                      --------                         --------------                                         
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB   Bus Number 0, Target Id 2, LUN 0 Intel(R) 300 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB   Bus Number 0, Target Id 3, LUN 0 Intel(R) 300 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB   Bus Number 0, Target Id 4, LUN 0 Intel(R) 300 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB   Bus Number 0, Target Id 5, LUN 0 Intel(R) 300 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
Samsung SSD 960 EVO 500GB Bus Number 0, Target Id 0, LUN 0 Standard NVM Express Controller
```

**Note:** Don't assume how many ports there are based on the location numbers. This motherboard only has 4 sata ports, but my listed IDs start at `2`.

---

There is no easy way to tell which how many ports are unused - Windows just does not track them. The best way to get that information is probably going to be looking up your motherboard specs online.

You can usually find your motherboard model through wmi for easy googling:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_baseboard | select Manufacturer,Product

Manufacturer                  Product              
------------                  -------              
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B250N Phoenix WIFI-CF
```

Comment: THANK YOU CptWhale!!!! EXCELLENT!!! Many thanks, really appreciated. thanks bot for your help and suggestions!

Comment: I have updated the filters in my answer to include cdrom devices, which are often also using SATA ports.

Comment: Someone **only** looking for SATA devices directly attached to the motherboard could use `Get-CimInstance win32_pnpsignedDriver -filter 'DeviceID LIKE "SCSI%"' | Select DeviceName,Location,DeviceID` and skip checking for other controllers.