# possible to know, by command line, where (what socket, sata, pcie, etc...) my internal DVD drive is connected to?

Tags: powershell, wmic

using command line (powershell, wmic, ...), I would need to know all the info about my internal DVD drive, including what port/socket is connected to, on the motherboard.

is it possible?

I only found something like these:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_diskdrive
```

or

```
wmic cdrom where mediatype!='unknown' get /format:list
```

but they got me not all the info (especially the socket where it is connected to)

thanks!

Comment: It is often not possible to reliably determine which physical port a drive is connected to on consumer hardware.

Comment: but do you know whether or not a command exists?

Comment: what are you trying to do that requires knowing the port? this seems like a classic x-y problem ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

I answered this [here](https://superuser.com/a/1706799/673426) but only for 'Disk Drive' type devices, so I have  updated the filters to include CD ROM devices like so:

```
# query for wmi objects
$drivers = Get-CimInstance win32_pnpsignedDriver -filter 'DeviceName="Disk drive" OR DeviceName="CD-ROM Drive"'
$disks = Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPEntity | ? {$_.service -in 'disk','cdrom' -and $_.name -ne 'Xvd'}  # Xvd is an xbox/windows-store-related device

# Iterate through disks
$result = foreach ($disk in $disks) {
  # disk controllers are usually either IDE (IDE/SATA) or SCSI (NVME/M.2/virtual)
  $controller = Get-CimInstance -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'}" | 
    Where {$_.CreationClassName -in 'Win32_IDEController','Win32_SCSIController'}

  # the driver class lists drive location
  $driver = $drivers | where DeviceID -eq $disk.PNPDeviceID

  # combine data for result
  $disk | select Name,
    @{l='location';e={$driver.Location}},
    @{l='controllerName';e={$controller.Name}}
}
$result
```

On my virtual machine, this outputs the list of hard drive and cd rom devices, and where they are plugged in:

```
Name                                 location                         controllerName   
----                                 --------                         --------------   
NECVMWar VMware SATA CD00            Bus Number 0, Target Id 0, LUN 0 Standard SATA ...
VMware Virtual disk SCSI Disk Device Bus Number 0, Target Id 0, LUN 0 LSI Adapter, S...
VMware Virtual disk SCSI Disk Device Bus Number 0, Target Id 1, LUN 0 LSI Adapter, S...
```

> Note: Don't assume how many ports there are based on the location numbers
>
> There is no easy way to tell which/how many ports are unused - Windows just does not track them. The best way to get that information is probably going to be looking up your motherboard specs online.